# gradle error on snapshot phase

Tags: gradle, gradlew

Hi i have got very strange error. First of all i build my project using the same command on linux (lubuntu x64) without any problem. But when i try build my project on redhat (aws) i have got error.

This is my stacktrace:

```
    17:19:45.313 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter] Executing actions for task ':snapshot'.
17:19:45.315 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.Project] Searching '/home/ec2-user/aexea-serverside/administration' for a '.hg' directory.
17:19:45.328 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.Project] Searching '/home/ec2-user/aexea-serverside' for a '.hg' directory.
17:19:45.328 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.Project] Searching '/home/ec2-user' for a '.hg' directory.
17:19:45.328 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.Project] Searching '/home' for a '.hg' directory.
17:19:45.328 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.Project] Searching '/' for a '.hg' directory.
17:19:45.328 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.Project] Could not locate a '.hg' directory.
17:19:45.412 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.Project] Searching '/home/ec2-user/aexea-serverside/administration' for a '.git' directory.
17:19:45.412 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.Project] Searching '/home/ec2-user/aexea-serverside' for a '.git' directory.
17:19:45.646 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter] Finished executing task ':snapshot'
17:19:45.646 [LIFECYCLE] [class org.gradle.TaskExecutionLogger] :snapshot FAILED
17:19:45.646 [INFO] [org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor] :snapshot (Thread[main,5,main]) completed. Took 0.335 secs.
17:19:45.647 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor] Task worker [Thread[main,5,main]] finished, busy: 0.478 secs, idle: 0.003 secs
17:19:45.652 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] 
17:19:45.653 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
17:19:45.653 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] 
17:19:45.653 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] * What went wrong:
17:19:45.653 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Execution failed for task ':snapshot'.
17:19:45.653 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] > java.lang.NullPointerException (no error message)
17:19:45.654 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] 
17:19:45.654 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] * Exception is:
17:19:45.655 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':snapshot'.
17:19:45.655 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:69)
17:19:45.655 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
17:19:45.655 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
17:19:45.655 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:64)
17:19:45.656 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
17:19:45.656 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:52)
17:19:45.656 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
17:19:45.656 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
17:19:45.656 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
17:19:45.668 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:203)
17:19:45.668 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:185)
17:19:45.668 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:66)
17:19:45.668 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:50)
17:19:45.669 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:25)
17:19:45.669 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:110)
17:19:45.669 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:37)
17:19:45.669 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
17:19:45.669 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$000(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
17:19:45.669 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:43)
17:19:45.669 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
17:19:45.670 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
17:19:45.670 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:30)
17:19:45.670 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$4.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:154)
17:19:45.670 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
17:19:45.670 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
17:19:45.671 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:52)
17:19:45.671 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:151)
17:19:45.672 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.access$200(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:32)
17:19:45.672 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:99)
17:19:45.672 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:93)
17:19:45.672 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
17:19:45.672 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:62)
17:19:45.672 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:93)
17:19:45.673 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:82)
17:19:45.673 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:94)
17:19:45.673 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ExecuteBuildActionRunner.run(ExecuteBuildActionRunner.java:28)
17:19:45.673 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
17:19:45.673 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:43)
17:19:45.673 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:28)
17:19:45.673 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:75)
17:19:45.673 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:45)
17:19:45.674 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.execute(DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.java:51)
17:19:45.674 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.execute(DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.java:28)
17:19:45.675 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:43)
17:19:45.675 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:170)
17:19:45.675 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:237)
17:19:45.675 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:210)
17:19:45.675 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:35)
17:19:45.675 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:24)
17:19:45.675 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:206)
17:19:45.675 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:169)
17:19:45.676 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
17:19:45.676 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
17:19:45.676 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:33)
17:19:45.676 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
17:19:45.676 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:54)
17:19:45.676 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:35)
17:19:45.689 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)
17:19:45.689 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start(BootstrapMainStarter.java:30)
17:19:45.689 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:129)
17:19:45.689 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
17:19:45.690 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
17:19:45.690 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at me.cmoz.gradle.snapshot.SnapshotTask.action(SnapshotTask.java:73)
17:19:45.690 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:75)
17:19:45.690 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.doExecute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:227)
17:19:45.690 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:220)
17:19:45.690 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:209)
17:19:45.690 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:585)
17:19:45.691 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:568)
17:19:45.691 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
17:19:45.691 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61)
17:19:45.691 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    ... 60 more
17:19:45.691 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] 
17:19:45.691 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.BuildResultLogger] 
17:19:45.692 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.BuildResultLogger] BUILD FAILED
```

Any idea ?

Comment: post your gradle file here, that might help

Comment: Do you have a VSC working copy on the aws machine as well?This plugin seems to look for VCS information so it assumes that you run the build from a checkout of a repository.

Comment: @fejese yes thats a problem i just add : 
git config --global user.name "Jan Nowak"
git config --global user.email jannowak@example.com

and its working like a charm :)